# how to use paginate with raw queries in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel-5

How to use paginate with raw queries in Laravel 5.3 ?

I have an error using this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

 $search=DB::select($sql)-paginate(10);

 return view('index', compact('search'));
```

Comment: Cool, and what's the error?

Comment: You are not following Raw queries correctly, in above statement your written `SELECT * FROM table` and below using Query Builder `DB::select().... ` ...  first clarify that what you want to do and your requirement ?